# Textcase, Listings, and Tilde

Tags: listings, tilde

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{textcase}

\RequirePackage{listings}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \MakeTextLowercase{A~B}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX fails with the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<to be read again> az
                     b
l.9     \MakeTextLowercase{A~B}

?
```

The error seems to lie in the combination of `MakeTextLowercase`, the `listings` package and the tilde. Whenever I remove any of these three components, everything works fine. Does anyone have a clue where the problem is?

Comment: linebreaks are important in tex error messages, I fixed your question to show the full errror.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `listings`: it's globally setting

```
\lccode`\~=`\z
```

which is not sensible. TeX is then lower casing `~` to `z` and not finding a definition for an active `z` (oddly enough). I'd suggest simply fixing this with

```
\lccode`\~=0\relax
```

immediately after

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

---

The bug itself is caused by the internal macro `\lst@CCPut`, which sets the `\lccode` for both `~` and `/` to a variety of values to set up internal data. Regrettably, this is not done in a group and there is no 'reset' code to put things back to normal, so we get 'junk' lower case mappings for these two code points.

Comment: Perfect answer - within minutes. Thanks!

Comment: I've reported this to the package maintainer: a fix is easy enough

Comment: @JosephWright have you ever heard anything back?

Comment: @stefanct Nope, never heard anything