# Listings appears to clash with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, listings

I'm using Overleaf. The following example appears to compile correctly:

**references.bib**

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@Article{Creasy1981,
  author    = {R. J. Creasy},
  title     = {The Origin of the {VM}/370~{T}ime-Sharing System},
  year      = {1981},
  volume    = {25},
  number    = {5},
  pages     = {483--490},
  issn      = {0018-8646},
  doi       = {10.1147/rd.255.0483},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1147/rd.255.0483},
  journal   = {{IBM} Journal of Research and Development},
  publisher = {{IBM}},
  type      = {Journal Article},
}
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
A reference \autocite{Creasy1981}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However, when the commented-out `listings` package is added back in, it complains at the `\printbibliography` line, asserting that `/370z` (I'm guessing in the title field of the bib entry - not sure where the `z` comes from though?) is some sort of control sequence.

```
./main.tex:11: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> /370z

l.11 \end
         {document}
```

I've removed the tilde, and there is now no problem, but I'm guessing the pre-filled DOI data had a non-breaking space there for a reason, so I'd rather it isn't removed. Why doesn't `listings` play nicely with this bib entry?

Comment: I've marked as a dupe here as the issue is really a bug in `listings` that manifests itself here: I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you! I guess the `biblatex` red herring threw off the duplicate search when I was asking the question. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listings doesn't clash directly with biblatex. But it changes (somewhere) the `\lccode` of the tilde and so lowercase breaks:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

%\lccode`\~=0 
\lowercase{~}

\end{document}
```

Actually there is a duplicate: [Textcase, Listings, and Tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302437/textcase-listings-and-tilde)
The answer of Joseph also identifies the place where the lccode is set.

Comment: So a dupe of the older question?

Comment: @JosephWright: Looks so. Did the maintainer answered to your message?