# Possible incompatibility between babel, listings and arsclassica

Tags: listings, babel

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[listings]{classicthesis} % or \usepackage{listings} - also causes the error
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{a~b}

\end{document}
```

The above code causes an error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   <<inserted text>> az;
>                      b
>   l.10     \paragraph{ab~cd}

After removing any one of three lines with packages: `babel`, `listings` or `arsclassica`, document compiles successfully.

What is important, changing `~` to  makes the code working again. Similarly, putting `~` outside disposition commands (`\paragraph{}`, `\section{}` etc.) to the text body also works.

I cannot trace the source of the error further.

Is it possible to use these three packages together in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302437/29873) in `listings`. As [Joseph Wright's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302440/29873) states:

Add

```
 \lccode`\~=0\relax
```

after loading `listings` to fix the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[listings]{classicthesis} % or \usepackage{listings} - also causes the error
\lccode`\~=0\relax % <-- the fix
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{a~b}

\end{document}
```