# Incompatibility between babel and listings when using quotes - how to overcome this?

Tags: listings, babel

With the following LaTeX file I get the error message

> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
>   <argument> {\lstinline {""}}
>
> l.11 \cmd{{\lstinline{""}}}

Commenting out `\usepackage[german]{babel}` makes the file compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\cmd{{\lstinline{""}}}

\end{document}
```

My goal is to have an empty string `""` plus some further strings within some text, and since I use `\lstinline` extensively otherwise, I would prefer to format those strings with `\lstinline` as well.  A potential workaround could be to format those strings without help of the listings package, but maybe there is a better solution.

For your reference: I also checked out [Possible incompatibility between babel, listings and arsclassica](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417317/128374) and [Textcase, Listings, and Tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302437/128374), but although it seemed to be a similar situation, this appears to be a different problem.

Comment: If you have `\lstinline` in the argument to another command, `listings` cannot do its normal job with category codes. A verbatim command (and `\lstinline` is included) should never appear as the argument to another command. What's the real purpose of `\cmd`?

Comment: Off-topic: Unless you must adhere to the pre-1997 orthography rules, you should specify the option `ngerman`, not `german`, when loading the `babel` package.

Comment: @egreg: I have stripped down my code to a minimal working example.  I use several commands in my document: Some are just for being able to create different versions of the document (sometimes with solutions shown, sometimes not, so I only have to centrally change a command), some are for factoring out common formatting stuff, so I can centrally change formatting.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann I understand, but the problem remains. Maybe a workaround can be found for `"`, but there are several other things that can and will go wrong when `\lstinline` is in the argument to another command.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks a lot - although I am not familiar with the internals of LaTeX like category codes, I now understand that the applicability of \lstinline is limited, and that this is probably not easy to fix - if it can be fixed at all.  I will thus replace \lstinline with some simpler formatting.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann That's why I asked about the intended working of `\cmd`.