# Babel and listings cause problem with hard spaces in sectioning headers in classicthesis

Tags: listings, babel, classicthesis, tilde, white-space

### Problematic MWE:

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}%\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}%\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}%\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{breaklines=true}

\begin{document}

%\tableofcontents

\chapter{Exemplary~chapter~title here}
\section{Exemplary~section~title here}

%\lstinputlisting{a.py}
\begin{lstlisting}
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
    a = 1;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Problems (highlighted in red in the images below):

1. The hard spaces (tildes) used in `chapter` and `section` commands are shown wrongly in page headers – sometimes as parts of the code from the problem-causing listing ended by a ‘)’ bracket (in this case as: ‘**␣␣␣␣␣␣a)**’) and sometimes just as the ‘)’ bracket.
2. One of the line breaks in `lstlisting` or `lstinputlisting` listing is lost. Shortly after, a critical listing length is reached that causes the header problems to occur.

Observations:

1. If the listing is shortened by removing a sufficient number of lines, the header problem on the last page covering the listing eventually disappears (previous pages seems to be still affected though).
2. Removing `\usepackage[english]{babel}` seems to prevent both problems from occuring.
3. Removing `\usepackage{classicthesis}` removes the problems as well.
4. This seems to be unrelated to the `` \lccode`\~=0\relax `` bug in `listings` package (e. g., [Textcase,
   Listings, and Tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302437)).

### The actual result:

[image: Erroneous result]

---

[image: Erroneous result (zoom)]

### Approximation of the desired result:

[image: Desired result]

---

[image: Desired result (zoom)]

Comment: Does the order in which you call the packages change anything? Call listings and babel before ct. What happens when  you remove the tildes?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Problem persists for all 6 possible orders of these 3 packages. Without any tilde in both chapter and section titles, the output is correct (also for Problem 2, i.e., missing line break in listing), but just a single tilde makes both problems occur again. Also, putting tilde only in the section title moves the listing breaking problem to the beginning to the next page (relatively to the pictures above).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to tell the exact cause of the problem but it's apparently a weird interaction between the `listings`, `babel` and `textcase` packages (where the latter is loaded by `classicthesis`). There seem to be four conditions required to trigger the problem:

1. The `~` command must be used in the text that goes into the heading. If you use normal spaces here, the output is fine.
2. A `lstlisting` must occur on the page and span over to the next page. The headings look normal if you just use plain dummy text.
3. The `babel` package must be loaded, such that the normal definition of the `~` command (`\nobreakspace {}`) is replaced by `\active@prefix ~\active@char~` which then somehow triggers the problem.
4. And finally, a `\lowercase` must be involved. `classicthesis` uses `textcase`'s `\MakeTextLowercase` command in the headings. This uses TeX's `\lowercase` primitive on `~` and thus leading to the strange behavior. You can see the same behavior if you redefine `\MakeTextLowercase` with `\def\MakeTextLowercase#1{\lowercase{#1}}`, but not with a simple `\def\MakeTextLowercase#1{#1}`.

Putting all that together, the `listings` bug you mentioned in your question actually does seem to be related here. At least that's what I think, because it somehow manipulates the lowercase code of `~`. So my suggested solution is to drop `babel`'s `~` implementation and use the original one:

```
\let\origtilde=~
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\let~=\origtilde
```