# Listings Package causes normal text to hyphenate at forward slashes

Tags: listings, line-breaking, hyphenation

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII hardware/software

\end{document}
```

This results in this output:

[image: With Listings]

If `\usepackage{listings}` is commented out, the hyphenation rules return to normal:

[image: Without Listings]

And just to note, in the actual environment I'm working in, it will also hyphenate between hard•ware, while with `listings` enabled, it hyphenates hardware/•software, as in the first image:

[image: Listings Further Example]

Two questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there a way to disable this? I don't really want this behaviour just because I'm typing code occasionally in a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

listings changes the \lccode of the slash to 47. This looks like a bug to me. Write to the maintainer.

As a workaround you can set it back to 0:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lccode`\/=0
\begin{document}

IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII hardware/software

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this same bug has been talked about before (but with the tilde) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302437/textcase-listings-and-tilde), and was reported three years ago. I'll try reporting again.

Comment: Did you ever receive a reply aka is this fixed with newer versions of the package?

Comment: @stefanct I just tried with a current texlive and it isn't fixed. But I don't know if someone actually reported it.

Comment: @trekky0623 could tell us, or even JosephWright (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302437/textcase-listings-and-tilde#comment733025_302440) ;)